# How do I execute python OpenCV programs without sudo?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, unix

I am trying python OpenCV and facing multiple issues (mostly permission related) as I cannot execute the video capture scripts without `sudo`. On the other hand, using `sudo` is creating permission issues with output files when they need to be shared with other processes.

When I'm not using sudo, this is the error message I get when `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` is called, `cv2` being `opencv` module:

```
cv2.error:/home/sidmeister/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:818: error: (-2) GStreamer: unable to start pipeline
in function cvCaptureFromCAM_GStreamer
```

Going through the source code I understand that [gst_element_set_state( )](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstElement.html#gst-element-set-state) function is returning `GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE`. And, as I understand, that's a permission issue!

So, I circle back to my original point, **is there any way to overcome these permission issues?**

Comment: Is your user a member of group `video`?

Comment: No. Can you explain please why that would work?

Comment: Assuming it is a permission issue in accessing the camera, this would make your user a member of a group that has access to it...

Comment: I added user to group `video`. Same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your user to the group `video`

```
gpasswd -a sidmeister video
```

Comment: Logout and login again.